# Is using the Google Sheets API to scrape my own spreadsheet against the terms of service?

Tags: google-sheets, google-cloud-platform, google-api

I've been writing a utility to sync a Google Sheets (which the organisation I'm a part of owns) to an SQL server, mostly for compatibility reasons while we develop our new backend.

My concern, however, is that the Google API Terms of Service states as follows:

> Unless expressly permitted by the content owner or by applicable law, you will not, and will not permit your end users or others acting on your behalf to, do the following with content returned from the APIs:

> Scrape, build databases, or otherwise create permanent copies of such content, or keep cached copies longer than permitted by the cache header;

https://developers.google.com/terms#e_prohibitions_on_content

In my case, is the 'content owner' myself, since I own the file on Drive, or Google, as it's stored on their servers? I'd really rather not get myself banned from Google, because we keep quite a bit of data in Drive.

Comment: You should have your organization's lawyers interpret your legal agreements. Stack overflow is targeted at programming questions and so this question is unsuited for this forum.

Answer (score 0):

I'm linking from official Google ToS which states that:

> As our Terms of Service state, "You retain ownership of any intellectual property rights that you hold in that content. In short, what belongs to you stays yours."

Here is the [link](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2450387?hl=en#:%7E:text=As%20our%20Terms%20of%20Service%20state%2C%20%22You%20retain%20ownership%20of%20any%20intellectual%20property%20rights%20that%20you%20hold%20in%20that%20content.%20In%20short%2C%20what%20belongs%20to%20you%20stays%20yours.%22)